# VAE: Noisy decoder output

Tags: autoencoders, variational-bayes, torch

I'm trying to implement a simple VAE by following several tutorials
[like this](https://towardsdatascience.com/variational-autoencoder-demystified-with-pytorch-implementation-3a06bee395ed) and [this](https://sannaperzon.medium.com/paper-summary-variational-autoencoders-with-pytorch-implementation-1b4b23b1763a). This is the code that I came up with:

```
class VAE(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self,input_shape,h_dim,z_dim):
    super(VAE,self).__init__()
    #Encoder, image to hidden space
    self.img_2hid = Modules.Linear(input_shape,h_dim)
    # From the hidden we move to z space and we get mu and std
    self.fc_mu,self.fc_std = Modules.Linear(h_dim,z_dim),Modules.Linear(h_dim,z_dim)
    # The decoder from the z space goes back to the hidden
    self.z_2hidden = Modules.Linear(z_dim,h_dim)
    # Finally from the hidden we go back to the input space
    self.hidden_2img = Modules.Linear(h_dim,input_shape)
    self.relu = Modules.Relu()
    self.rloss = torch.nn.MSELoss('sum')


def encode(self,x):
    x = self.relu(self.img_2hid(x))
    return self.fc_mu(x),torch.log(self.fc_std(x))

def decode(self,x):
    x = self.relu(self.z_2hidden(x))
    return self.relu(self.hidden_2img(x))

def normalize(self,x):
    v_min, v_max = x.min(), x.max()
    new_min, new_max = torch.Tensor([0]).float(), torch.Tensor([255]).float()
    x = torch.add(torch.mul(torch.div(torch.sub(x, v_min), torch.sub(v_max, v_min)), torch.sub(new_max, new_min)),new_min)
    return x

def forward(self,x):
    original = x.shape
    # encode x to get the mu and variance parameters
    mu, log_sigma = self.encode(x.reshape(-1))
    # sample z from q
    sigma = torch.exp(log_sigma)
    epsilon = torch.randn_like(sigma)
    z = mu + sigma * epsilon
    # decoded
    x_hat = self.normalize(self.decode(z)).reshape(original)
    # reconstruction loss
    recon_loss = self.rloss(x_hat,x)
    # kl
    # The formula here is suppose for a normal distribution for q(z|x)
    kl_div = - 0.5 * torch.sum(1 + torch.log(sigma) * 2 - mu.pow(2) - torch.exp(log_sigma*2)) 
    # elbo
    elbo = recon_loss + kl_div
    return elbo,recon_loss,kl_div,x_hat
```

The problem that I’m having is that the output of the decoder is extremely noisy. For reference by training on this image (the image is normalized with mean 0 and std 1):

[image]

I get:

[image]

Any ideas why?